# Which characters does this LOST promo refer to?

Tags: character-identification, lost, advertisements

A strange, avant garde *LOST* season one promo was shown in the United Kingdom. It referred to various characters from the show. However, many of the lines from it don't really make sense to me.

The lines, broken down are this:

> All of us have a secret.

True.

> One of us is a hero.

This probably refers to Jack, but I could see it referring to any number of people.

> One of us is a fraud.

I have no idea which specific character this refers to.

> One of us is a junkie.

Charlie, obviously.

> One of us is a cop[?].

I don't think this applies to any season one character shown in the ad, assuming I'm hearing it correctly.

> One of us is a saint.

No idea.

> One of us is a sinner.

Most or all of them, in some way or another.

> One of us is a martyr.

Again, no idea.

> One of us is a murderer.

Well,

> both Kate and Sawyer are murderers,

so this is technically true, but also sort of wrong as it implies that there's only one murderer.

> All of us are guilty.

Of something, yes, but I don't see how many of them are guilty of anything major.

> All of us are lost.

True.

Which character(s) is each line supposed to refer to? As it's a season one promo, please try to have a season one mind-set in your answers.

Comment: "Cop" is a bit simple, but probably the best fit of the main cast was onscreen during the line:  Sayid was with the Iraqi Republican Guard.  Jin was in the military as well, but it didn't have nearly as much effect on him as Sayid's past did.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**This first paragraph was intended to be a comment but is way too long**: First of all, it is a promo video for a show so its content should be taken with a grain of salt. Most of the time, it is made by the broadcaster, not by the producers of the show, so it can be fairly inaccurate. It is made to advertise the show and make people want to see it. Here, it seems that it comes directly from the producers but it is fair to assume that it was made early in the making of the show, so even the producers didn't know fully how the show will evolve. This promo plays more on the mysterious feature ("Everybody has a secret") and the contrast of the cast (how can they cooperate to survive if they are so different?) rather than a precise description of each protagonist.

Also, "one of them" is often logically interpreted as "at least one of them" rather than "exactly one of them", so you shouldn't be looking for a one-to-one correspondence between characters and descriptions.

That said, let's break down the list (obvious **UNMARKED SPOILERS** ahead).

1. **All of us have a secret**: As you said, most of the characters have a secret. Some more than one, but it is fine, "a secret" can mean "at least a secret".
2. **One of us is a hero**: From the pilot, we can guess it is Jack indeed. He was actually supposed to be killed in the pilot, because J.J.Abrams liked the idea of the audience being shocked by the death of the main asset of the group. He changed his mind after pre-screening of the pilot seeing how much people loved Jack. But this also reveal another ambiguity: should the character be a hero before coming to the island? Or become one (revealed to be a heroic person) on the island? In the second interpretation, most of the main cast, including Sawyer, have their heroic moment.
3. **One of us is a fraud**: Sawyer is a con, Kate is a criminal. Locke pretends to be a badass with survivor skills, whereas he is almost as clueless as the the other characters.
4. **One of us is a junkie**: yes, Charlie, obviously. In addition, isn't suggested in the pilot that Jack could be alcoholic?
5. **One of us is a cop**: I guess it is for the US Marshall that is with Kate. He is not in the main cast, but do audience really cares who is officially the main cast? Frederic Lane, who portrays him, is a fairly well-known face in the TV shows panorama.
6. **One of us is a saint**: Not the clearest point. Depending on the interpretation of saint, you could imagine the innocent pregnant girl Claire, or kid Walt. And with the tortuous mystic vibe of the show, you could almost see Locke as a saint (showing the way to the faith to his fellows - one of the episodes centered around Locke is titled "man of faith, man of science"). Or Rose, the always-quiet lady.
7. **One of us is a sinner**: Same as above, depending on the interpretation of sinner. With the first season being open to many interpretation, and the theory of the island being some kind of purgatory, it can apply to most of them. Aren't we all sinner in some way?
8. **One of us is a martyr**: Not clear indeed. Maybe Locke, who suffered a lot in his life. It could be said that him suffering a lot all his life was a way to prepare him for his destiny on the island. Jack also has some aspects of a martyr, sacrificing his life for his cause (medicine).
9. **One of us is a murderer**: Kate and Sawyer are indeed murderers. It is definitely true. Also, Jin is seen working for Sun's father, and the extend of what he can do to help his boss is left unclear for some time.
10. **All of us are guilty**: Hum, no one is fully innocent, be it morally or legally. And if you take a mystical/religious/fate-like interpretation of the show, they are all guilty of being alive, and not accomplishing a better destiny.
11. **All of us are lost**: Lost on the island. And also lost in their life.

Of course, all of this is subject to interpretation. But the show was all about ambiguity and grey area. Note that there are 8 *one of us* sentences, with 14 main actors (without counting the important season one supporting characters like the US Marshall,or Rose, or Danielle Rousseau), so it was never intended to be a *one sentence-one character* thing.

Comment: Martyr is taking about locks friend that dies in season 1

Comment: @bryan Boone? I could definitely see that.

Comment: While "One of us" could mean "at least one of us" it generally implies a single person.

Comment: "Two of us are murderers" would have been much more of a spoiler, wouldn't it.

Comment: Edward Mars and Ana Lucia are only reasonable cop characters. She appears in S1, so it’s not too much stretch it could be her. Although Mars gets a lot of mileage in flashbacks.